# Pop up data is not clearing in Richfaces 4.0

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am new to Rich Faces and we are using richfaces 4.0. We are having an pop up requirement in our project and we used rich:popupPanel.
In the pop up we are having a form with 5 to 10 input text boxes and selectManyCheckbox components.

Whenever the user opens the pop up, fills the data and click Save, the data is being saved properly. 
But when the user opens the pop up again, the already entered data is being displayed, actually it should be an empty form.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the popup code and The function which saves the data

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the backing bean that supply the values to your controls in the `rich:popupPanel` is in the session scoped and you forget to clear these values in the action method when the save button in the `rich:popupPanel` is pressed.

Please check if you really clear these values in that action method

Comment: He will probably need to use render="modalPanel" too, if he use an ajax button for the saving.